# Connecting to switches using SSH and Expect

Tags: ssh, tcl, expect

I'm a newbie to expect (lot's of shell programming though).
I'm trying to connect to a switch using expect to be able to dump it's running config. But somehow my send commands appear not be send to the switch.

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

proc connect {passw} {
  expect {
    "assword:" {
      send "$passw\r"
        expect {
          "Prompt>" {
            return 0
          }
        }
    }
  }
   # timed out
   return 1
 }

set user [lindex $argv 0]
set passw [lindex $argv 1]
set host [lindex $argv 2]

#check if all were provided
if { $user == "" || $passw == "" || $host == "" } {
  puts "Usage: <user> <passw> <host>\n"
  exit 1
}

spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no $user@$host
set rez [connect $passw]
if { $rez == 0 } {
    send {enable\r}
    send {show running\r}
    exit 0
}
puts "\nError connecting to switch: $host, user: $user!\n"
exit 1
```

Alas when I run the script (trigged from a shell script) I can see it login to the switch and see the 'Prompt', but after that the script seems to exit, because I don't see the 'enable' and 'show running' commands being executed.

Anyone can show me how to fix this?

Richard.

Comment: Not an answer (hence a comment) but you might want to look at how rancid (http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/) does this.

Answer (score 1):

You need add further `expect` statement after sending the commands using `send`.

```
spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no $user@$host
set rez [connect $passw]

set prompt "#"

if { $rez == 0 } {
    send {enable\r}
    expect $prompt; # Waiting for 'prompt' to appear
    send {show running\r}
    expect $prompt; # Waiting for the prompt to appear
    exit 0
}
```

Without the `expect` command after using `send`, then expect has nothing to expect from the ssh process and it will simply send the commands in a faster way which is why you are not able to get any output.

**One more update :**

You are using a separate `proc` for login purpose. If you are using a separate `proc`, then you are recommended to pass the spawn handle. Else, the script may fail. The reason is, instead of send/expect from the process, it will send/expect from the stdin. So, you should have used it like this,

```
proc connect {passw handle} {
  expect {
    -i $handle 
    "assword:" {
      send "$passw\r"
        expect {
          -i $handle
          "Prompt>" {
            return 0
          }
        }
    }
  }
   # timed out
   return 1
 }

 set handle [ spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no $user@$host ] 
 set rez [connect $passw $handle ]
 set prompt "#"
 if { $rez == 0 } {
    send -i $handle "enable\r"
    expect -i $handle $prompt
    send -i $handle "show running\r"
    expect -i $handle $prompt
    exit 0
}
```

We are saving the ssh spawn handle into the variable `'handle'` and it is being used with `send` and `expect` and the flag `-i` is used to make them to wait for the corresponding process

Comment: The spawn_id is global, and expect uses a different scoping mechanism then Tcl: you should not have to explicitly pass the spawn_id to the proc.

Comment: Yes Glenn. Correct. I made it like this to avoid any possible problems, like more than one spawn being used in script

Answer (score 0):

@Dinesh has the main answer. A couple of other notes:

- `send {enable\r}` -- since you use braces instead of quotes, you are sending the characters <kbd>\</kbd> and <kbd>r</kbd> and not a carriage return.
- you return 0 and 1 from `connect` like you're a shell programmer (not an insult, I am one too). Use Tcl's boolean values instead.

A quick rewrite:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set prompt "Prompt>"
proc connect {passw} {
    expect "assword:" 
    send "$passw\r"
    expect {
        $::prompt {return true}
        timeout   {return false} 
    }
}

lassign $argv user passw host

#check if all were provided
if { $user == "" || $passw == "" || $host == "" } {
    puts "Usage: [info script] <user> <passw> <host>"
    exit 1
}

spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no $user@$host
if {[connect $passw]} {
    send "enable\r"
    expect $::prompt
    send "show running\r"
    expect $::prompt
    send "exit\r"         # neatly close the session
    expect eof
} else {
    puts "\nError connecting to switch: $host, user: $user!\n"
}
```